# Creating Vocabulary in python

Tags: python, text, nltk, vocabulary

I have a number of text file. I would like to use NLTK for preprocessing and printing the vocabulary in a plain text .text format, so that I can distribute those file for the people to use. I did following to do it.I started with taking single file:

```
file1 = open("path/to/text/file","rU")
raw = file1.read()
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
words = [w.lower for w in tokens]
vocab = sorted(set(tokens))
```

Now i would like to list of items in vocab into a plain text `.txt` human 
readable file. How would I do it?

Comment: One mistake that is there in your question is that after lower captioning the words, you are not using them to build your vocab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it out manually:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in vocab:
        f.write(item + "\n")
```

Comment: Or just `f.writelines(vocab)` :)

Comment: Not quite: `writelines` does not add newlines, so the current answer is right.